# kivy bind() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (0 given)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am building a elevator system GUI in python() with kivy. I'm writing it so that when an up-button of a floor is pressed, a function will be called, which will generate a request and send it to the system. I am now trying to bind the function to the up-button using:

```
self.floor1.up_button.bind(on_press=self.up_pressed(1))
```

And the compiler sends me an error:

```
TypeError: bind() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (0 given)
```

Is there a fix to it? Python beginner, so apologies if this is a really simple question.

Here are the relevant codes in the .py file:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from random import randint

class FloorRequestStatus:
    up = 0
    down = 1

class Request:
    def __init__(self, start, status, destination, waiting_time):
        self.start = start
        self.status = status
        self.destination = destination
        self.waiting_time = waiting_time

class Floor(GridLayout):
    up_count = NumericProperty(0)
    down_count = NumericProperty(0)
    floor_index = NumericProperty(0)

    up_button = ObjectProperty(Button)
    down_button = ObjectProperty(Button)

class FloorSystem(BoxLayout):
    floor1 = ObjectProperty(Floor)  # type:Floor
    floor2 = ObjectProperty()
    floor3 = ObjectProperty()
    floor4 = ObjectProperty()

    floors = [floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4]

    request_queue = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloorSystem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.floor1.up_button.bind(on_press=self.up_pressed(1))

    def generate_destination(self, floor_index, status):
        if status == FloorRequestStatus.up:
            return randint(floor_index + 1, 20)
        if status == FloorRequestStatus.down:
            return randint(0, floor_index - 1)

    def up_pressed(self, floor_index):
        a_request = Request(floor_index, FloorRequestStatus.up,
                        self.generate_destination(floor_index,FloorRequestStatus.up), 0)
        self.request_queue.append(a_request)
```

And these are the relevant codes in .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Floor@GridLayout>
    floor_index: 0
    pos: 200,200
    rows: 1
    spacing: 1

    GridLayout:
        size_hint_x: 35
        cols: 1

        Button:
            id: up_button
            size_hint_y: 50
            text: 'up'
            on_press: root.up_count += 1

        Button:
            id:down_button
            size_hint_y: 50
            text: 'down'
            on_press: root.down_count += 1

    Label:
        id: floor_label
        size_hint_x: 65
        text: root.label_text
        background_color: 1,1,1,1
        text: str(root.floor_index) + 'F (' + str(root.up_count) + ',' + str(root.down_count) + ')'

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .3, .5, 1, .4
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

<FloorSystem>
    floor1: floor1
    floor2: floor2
    floor3: floor3
    floor4: floor4

    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: None, None
    width: 160
    height: 700
    spacing: 2

    Floor:
        id: floor4
        floor_index: 4

    Floor:
        id: floor3
        floor_index: 3

    Floor:
        id: floor2
        floor_index: 2

    Floor:
        id: floor1
        floor_index: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the original code, you will encounter the following error.

## Error

```
         self.floor1.up_button.bind(on_press=self.up_pressed(1))
     TypeError: descriptor 'bind' of 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher' object needs an argument
```

## Explanation

The above error occurred because *up_button* is hooked up to a *Button class* and not hooked up to a Button object. If you insert print statement, `print(self.floor1.up_button)` into your program you will see the difference.

[Event dispatcher](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html)

> In general, property callbacks are called with 2 arguments (the object and the property’s new value) and event callbacks with one argument (the object).

## Solution

### Python Script - Remove Button

Replace:

```
up_button = ObjectProperty(Button)
down_button = ObjectProperty(Button)
```

With:

```
up_button = ObjectProperty(None)
down_button = ObjectProperty(None)
```

### kv file - Hookup ObjectProperties

```
<Floor@GridLayout>
    up_button: up_button
    down_button: down_button

    floor_index: 0
    ...
```

### Button Binding

As for the binding, you can use partial function.

```
self.floor1.up_button.bind(on_press=partial(self.up_pressed, 1))
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from random import randint
from functools import partial


class FloorRequestStatus:
    up = 0
    down = 1


class Request:
    def __init__(self, start, status, destination, waiting_time):
        self.start = start
        self.status = status
        self.destination = destination
        self.waiting_time = waiting_time


class Floor(GridLayout):
    up_count = NumericProperty(0)
    down_count = NumericProperty(0)
    floor_index = NumericProperty(0)

    up_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    down_button = ObjectProperty(None)


class FloorSystem(BoxLayout):
    floor1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    floor2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    floor3 = ObjectProperty(None)
    floor4 = ObjectProperty(None)

    floors = [floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4]

    request_queue = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloorSystem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.floor1.up_button.bind(on_press=partial(self.up_pressed, 1))

    def generate_destination(self, floor_index, status):
        if status == FloorRequestStatus.up:
            return randint(floor_index + 1, 20)
        if status == FloorRequestStatus.down:
            return randint(0, floor_index - 1)

    def up_pressed(self, floor_index):
        a_request = Request(floor_index, FloorRequestStatus.up,
                            self.generate_destination(floor_index, FloorRequestStatus.up), 0)
        self.request_queue.append(a_request)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return FloorSystem()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Floor@GridLayout>
    up_button: up_button
    down_button: down_button

    floor_index: 0
    pos: 200,200
    rows: 1
    spacing: 1

    GridLayout:
        size_hint_x: 35
        cols: 1

        Button:
            id: up_button
            size_hint_y: 50
            text: 'up'
            on_press: root.up_count += 1

        Button:
            id:down_button
            size_hint_y: 50
            text: 'down'
            on_press: root.down_count += 1

    Label:
        id: floor_label
        size_hint_x: 65
        text: root.label_text
        background_color: 1,1,1,1
        text: str(root.floor_index) + 'F (' + str(root.up_count) + ',' + str(root.down_count) + ')'

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .3, .5, 1, .4
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

<FloorSystem>
    floor1: floor1
    floor2: floor2
    floor3: floor3
    floor4: floor4

    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: None, None
    width: 160
    height: 700
    spacing: 2

    Floor:
        id: floor4
        floor_index: 4

    Floor:
        id: floor3
        floor_index: 3

    Floor:
        id: floor2
        floor_index: 2

    Floor:
        id: floor1
        floor_index: 1
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: THANKS! A really detailed explanation. Actually there's another mistake that I use Floor class instead of Floor object when creating the floor1, the ObjectProperty.

Comment: @GaryYuan: You are welcome. Don't need to instantiate *Floor* in `floor1 = ObjectProperty(Floor())' because the ObjectProperty *floor1* is already hooked up to an instantiated children widget, *floor1* in the *kv file*. Due to this the program works and did not throw an error. I have removed *Floor()* to avoid confusion.